# New line in Javascript or HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var symbol = prompt("Please choose a symbol");
var side = prompt("Choose the length of the square");
var count1 = 1;
var count2 = 1;
while (count1 <= side) {
    while (count2 <= side) {
        document.write(symbol);
        var count2 = count2 + 1;
    }
    document.writeln()
    var count2 = 1;
    var count1 = count1 + 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kjQB9/36/

I am working with the code above. I'm trying to get JS to draw a box out of a given input. I have read about the \n\r and 
 codes but I have not be able to place them somewhere to get the lines to form a square. For instance if I input * and 3. I want output to be:

```
***
***
***
```

But it's appearing as `*** *** ***`.

Where can I include these tags, and should it be done in HTML or JS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just 
include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; 
consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future!

Comment: Sorry about that! Will definitely include code next time! Good point about fiddle going down! Thanks!

Comment: `document.write(symbol + "<br>");`

Comment: The `writeln` won't visually go to a new line. Use `document.write("<br>")`.

Comment: My goodness. I can't believe I had to ask, or had the nerve to ask this question back then. I've come so far since then and in part due to Stack Overflow. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `<br>` tag for a break. The `\r` or `\n` are line breaks, but HTML ignores most whitespace.

Comment: Can you help with the placement of the tags?